# Passing in parameter to decorator in a different class

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing, decorator, python-decorators

I wanted to see if it's possible to pass in a parameter to a decorator that sits in a script that is being called from a different script where that parameter exists. So for example, let's say I have `script_1.py` which is calling the method:

```
import function_1

param_1 = 5
result = function_1(arg1, arg2)
```

Now this function sits in `script_2.py` where the decorator takes in `param_1`

```
@decorator(param_1)
def function_1(arg1, arg2):
    #do some stuff
```

So is there any way to call the function w/decorator in `script_1.py` and pass in `param_1` into the decorator in `script_2.py`?

Comment: No; the decorator is applied when *defining* `function_1`, it's far too late post-`import`.

Comment: By the time you have imported `script_2.py`, the decorator has already run.

Comment: So is there a different way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: We don't know what you're actually trying to do, because of the abstract example, so that's very difficult to answer. Maybe leave out the decorator where you define `function_1` then just call `decorator(param_1)(function_1)(arg1, arg2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorators run immediately after the `def` statement has been evaluated.

```
@decorator(param1)
def function_1(arg1, arg2):
    ...
```

is equivalent to

```
def function_1(arg1, arg2):
    ...

function_1 = decorator(param1)(function_1)
```

This code runs when you execute the `import` statement, not when you call `function_1`.